# Como substituir parte, de ordem específica, de uma string?

Tags: javascript, string

Gostaria de saber como substituir parte de uma string, mas apenas parte de ordem N.

Por exemplo, substituir o segundo (tão somente) "e" de "eletricidade".

> Entrada: Eletricidade
>
> Saída: Eltricidade

Talvez seja simples, mas sou leigo no assunto... já tentei por `split` e `replace`,  não consegui.

Comment: Mas a substituição é susposto não diferenciar maisculas de minusculas ? Quando diz substituir o segundo `e` esse na verdade seria o primeiro `e` minusculo.

Answer (score 2):

Criei uma função que usa o `indexOf` para procurar a string a ser substituída dentro da entrada e um `for` para iterar nela e procurar a ocorrência correta a ser substituída.

Uma vez que a parte a ser substituída é encontrada na string, o método `substring` pode ser utilizado para montar uma nova string ao concatenar aa parte da entrada que tem o que está antes do pedaço a ser substituído, o substituto do pedaço a ser substituído e então a parte da entrada que tem o que há depois do trecho substituído.

Se a parte a ser substituída não for encontrada, a string de entrada é alterada inaletrada.

Segue o código da função junto com o código de teste correspondente:

```js
function substituir(entrada, substituindo, substituto, ordem) {
    if (ordem === 0) return entrada;
    var upEntrada = entrada.toUpperCase();
    var upSubstituindo = substituindo.toUpperCase();
    var idx = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ordem; i++) {
        idx = upEntrada.indexOf(upSubstituindo, idx + 1);
        if (idx === -1) return entrada;
    }
    return entrada.substring(0, idx)
            + substituto
            + entrada.substring(idx + substituindo.length);
}

var teste1 = "Eletricidade";
var saida1 = substituir(teste1, "e", "", 2);
document.write(teste1 + " - " + saida1 + "<br>");

var teste2 = "Ana, Mariana e Luciana gostam de comer banana.";
var saida2 = substituir(teste2, "ana", "mara", 3);
document.write(teste2 + " - " + saida2 + "<br>");

var teste3 = "Azul Verde Vermelho Lilás Verde Roxo";
var saida3 = substituir(teste3, "verde", "Branco", 0);
var saida4 = substituir(teste3, "verde", "Branco", 1);
var saida5 = substituir(teste3, "verde", "Branco", 2);
var saida6 = substituir(teste3, "verde", "Branco", 3);

document.write(teste3 + " - " + saida3 + "<br>");
document.write(teste3 + " - " + saida4 + "<br>");
document.write(teste3 + " - " + saida5 + "<br>");
document.write(teste3 + " - " + saida6 + "<br>");

var teste7 = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var saida7 = substituir(teste7, "X", "Y", 2);
var saida8 = substituir(teste7, "A", "Z", 999);
var saida9 = substituir(teste7, "A", "Z", 5);
document.write(teste7 + " - " + saida7 + "<br>");
document.write(teste7 + " - " + saida8 + "<br>");
document.write(teste7 + " - " + saida9 + "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma, usando *Expressão Regular* com `.replace` (explicações no código):

```js
// parâmetros da função:
// t = texto
// x = texto a ser substituído
// y = novo texto
// p = posição da ocorrência
function subs(t,x,y,p){
   var c = 0;                        // contador
   var r = new RegExp(x,'gi');       // regex: busca em todo texto e não diferencia maiúscula de minúscula
   t = t.replace(r, function(m){     // faz o replace
     c++;                            // incrementa o contador
     return (c == p) ? y : m;        // retorna para a função a string substituída na posição desejada
   });                               // se não encontrar ocorrência, retorna o texto original
   return t;                         // retorna o resultado da função
}

// exemplos
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "", 2) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "X", 1) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "X", 3) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "ic", "IC", 1) );
console.log( subs("Abracadabra", "Bra", "-", 2) );
```

**Código limpo (sem comentários):**

```js
function subs(t,x,y,p){
   var c = 0;
   var r = new RegExp(x,'gi');
   t = t.replace(r, function(m){
     c++;
     return (c == p) ? y : m;
   });
   return t;
}

console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "", 2) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "X", 1) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "e", "X", 3) );
console.log( subs("Eletricidade", "ic", "IC", 1) );
console.log( subs("Abracadabra", "bra", "-", 2) );
```

Comment: porque não tudo  `toUpperCase()`. A essa hora com esse sono daria pra enxergar melhor né

Comment: Onde vc viu isso? rsrs

Comment: Acho que sonhei!! E no sonho andei vendo coisas! hahaha